# Why can't install yfinance in custom directory?

Tags: python, installation, package

Many python packages were installed in my `.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages`,and i had already tried that

```
pip install git+https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance
```

`yfinance` can be installed in `.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages`.Now i am trying to install with downloaded package.
Download a specified yfinance version on `https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance` and extract it.

```
cd /home/debian/Downloads/yfinance-hotfix-proxy
ls
build          LICENSE.txt  mkdocs.yml        setup.cfg  test_yfinance.py
CHANGELOG.rst  MANIFEST.in  README.md         setup.py   yfinance
dist           meta.yaml    requirements.txt  tests  yfinance.egg-info
```

Install with `--prefix`:

```
debian@debian:~/Downloads/yfinance-hotfix-proxy$ python3 setup.py install --prefix /home/debian/.local
running install
/home/debian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
/home/debian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py:144: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
error: Cannot update time stamp of directory 'yfinance.egg-info'
```

Why can't install it with `python3 setup.py install --prefix /home/debian/.local`?

Comment: Which version from github are you trying to install ? I downloaded the latest and I don't have the same files as you, no `yfinance.egg-info` file for example.

Comment: https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/tree/hotfix/proxy

Comment: Maybe permission problem from a previous failed installation ? Does it change something if you delete the folder `yfinance.egg-info` and try again ? No problem on my side using the link you provided, I'm using python 3.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a similar error ("`Cannot update time stamp of directory`") in another python project [`r0oth3x49/ghauri` issue 52](https://github.com/r0oth3x49/ghauri/issues/52).

That issue suggested:

- to use `pip install .` instead of `python3 -m pip install -e .` or `python3 setup.py install`
- to use `sudo`, which is not recommended.

The first point is in line with the warning messages you are seeing: it  suggests that `setup.py install` is deprecated, and recommend using `pip` instead.

If possible, try using `pip` to install the package directly from the downloaded files, like this: `pip install . --prefix /home/debian/.local`. This command should be run from the directory that contains the `setup.py` file.